# is it possible to copy package components in sandbox?

Tags: managed-package, sandbox

I am having my own managed package installed in sandbox. Its not working. So I need to replicate all fields, Objects, workflows, apex Classes present in package to my Sandbox.
So is it possible to export all components to sandbox?
Any help appriciated.

Comment: why not just debug in the org you develop in?

Comment: it is working in dev org but not in sandbox

Comment: Is there any way to replicate all stuff?

Comment: If you know what is not happening then review the code for namespace issues.  basic debugging will narrow it down, then you can copy and paste relevant code in sandbox to debug on

Comment: might just be easier to ask the question here...someone should be able to identify issue with the appropriate info

Comment: since I cant debug package so I need it in my sandbox. So that I can debug

Comment: you wrote the code, narrow down to what is not happening and replicate that part if needed

Comment: if you have your own. you can create unmanaged package and deploy that in Sandbox or export in eclipse and deploy in your sandbox.

Comment: Can you please Elaborate the solution